# Android HttpURLConnection SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android, web-services, socket-timeout-exception

we are calling several web services from android app that returns JSON data but only one of them is working correctly, the rest throws java.net.SocketTimeoutException.
All web services are equals, the only difference is the amount of data returned.

I have tested web services from postman working okey.
I have tested web services using the same executeRequest method in a simple Java application working okey, calling one by one or in a loop.
I have tested web services from emulator Android Virtual Device (Nexus 5 API 23 v.6) working okey !!!

```
private String executeRequest(String theUrl) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15 * 1000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(15 * 1000);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
            br.close();

            return response.toString();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

But when I debugged the method in different devices (Galaxy Nexus v4.3, Galaxy Tab v4.2.2 and Nexus 5 v6.0.1), as I said, only one web service is returning data. Any important thing is that web services are reached from the app but connection.getInputStream() is throwing the socketTimeoutException.

I have tried to use different libraries as OkHttp or Volley with the same result.

This is the build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        ...
    }
}
```

I attach the logcat:

```
07-18 11:51:49.677 16030-20533/app W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:484)
     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.-wrap0(PlainSocketImpl.java)
     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
     at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:135)
     at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306)
     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300)
     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:904)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:788)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:443)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
```

Comment: `connection.setDoOutput(true);`. You promise here that you will send some data. You also promised to POST. But you are sending nothing. You are posting nothing. But the webservice is expecting you to do so and waits. Waits.

Comment: I have removed this line but the same exception is thrown.

Comment: You should send some data. You should post something. You should send that json text. The webservice expects json as your content type is as such.

Comment: I have changed webservice and request method type = GET but the exception is the same.

Comment: Try that url in a browser on your Android device.

Comment: Your post is a mess. If all is for a GET than adapt the code here too.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed for testing but method is POST.

In your last answer I have found the solution, that is, when I use the andorid device browser to navigate the url it is not working due to I'm sharing the laptop connection with device.

I have publish the web services in other IP address and all works fine!

Thanks for all.